# Can't create an SSL connection with Maven and Jetty

Tags: java, web-services, maven, ssl, jetty

I've a Web Service running with Jetty and Maven. Now, I would like to create an SSL connection for this WS. 
I apply this code in my pom.xml file:

**pom.xml** :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>5</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>9090</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
                <port>443</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                <keystore>jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
                <password>jetty6</password>
                <keyPassword>jetty6</keyPassword>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>keytool-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>clean</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <id>genkey</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generateKeyPair</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <keystore>jetty-ssl.keystore</keystore>
        <dname>cn=NCSL004</dname>
        <keypass>jetty6</keypass>
        <storepass>jetty6</storepass>
        <alias>jetty6</alias>
        <keyalg>RSA</keyalg>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And when I run maven I get:

```
>       [INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.13.v20130916:run (default-cli) @ Test >>> 

>       [INFO] --- keytool-maven-plugin:1.3:clean (clean) @ Test ---
>       [INFO] Keystore file 'jetty-ssl.keystore' deleted successfully.
>       [INFO] 
>       [INFO] --- keytool-maven-plugin:1.3:generateKeyPair (genkey) @ Test ---
>       [INFO] 
>
>       ...
>
>       2013-12-13 10:47:46.160:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started             
>       SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 <br />
>       [INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

When I'm trying to connect on [https://localhost:443] I get an error, in addition in [http://localhost:9090] I get an error too!
So my web service only works on [http://localhost:8080]. It seems that Maven doesn't implements the port configurations.

How can I solve this error?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A few things ...

1. Port `443` is within the special reserved space (ports 1 thru 1024), so binding to it from a non-priviledged user is not going to happen.
2. You are using jetty-8.1.13, but that's in the `org.eclipse.jetty` namespace, not `org.mortbay.jetty`, so your `<connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">` lines are all wrong for Jetty 8.  Those entries are for Jetty 6 and earlier.

For Jetty 8, it would look like this ...

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>8.1.14.v20131031</version>
  <configuration>
    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
    <webApp>
      <contextPath>/test</contextPath>
    </webApp>
    <connectors>
       <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>9090</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
       </connector>
       <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
          <port>9443</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
          <keystore>src/test/resources/server.keystore</keystore>
          <keyPassword>123456</keyPassword>
          <password>123456</password>
       </connector>
     </connectors>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```